# Possible memory leak or something else?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I've made a visualizer in javascript that when you select a music directory your're able to select files within that directory to play and have the visualizer move to. But it would seem after loading a directory and then changing the song more than 4 times Results in less responsive movement from the visualizer. I'm unsure why this is happening.
Heres an example of this happening.

Keep changing the song from the drop down box until you see it starting to slow.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("file");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  var selectLabel = document.querySelector("label[for=select]");
  var audioLabel = document.querySelector("label[for=audio]");
  var select = document.querySelector("select");
  var context = void 0,
    src = void 0,
    res = [],
    url = "";

  function processDirectoryUpload(event) {
    var webkitResult = [];
    var mozResult = [];
    var files;
    console.log(event);
    select.innerHTML = "";

    // do mozilla stuff
    function mozReadDirectories(entries, path) {
      console.log("dir", entries, path);
      return [].reduce.call(entries, function(promise, entry) {
          return promise.then(function() {
            return Promise.resolve(entry.getFilesAndDirectories() || entry)
              .then(function(dir) {
                return dir
              })
          })
        }, Promise.resolve())
        .then(function(items) {
          var dir = items.filter(function(folder) {
            return folder instanceof Directory
          });
          var files = items.filter(function(file) {
            return file instanceof File
          });
          if (files.length) {
            // console.log("files:", files, path);
            mozResult = mozResult.concat.apply(mozResult, files);
          }
          if (dir.length) {
            // console.log(dir, dir[0] instanceof Directory);
            return mozReadDirectories(dir, dir[0].path || path);

          } else {
            if (!dir.length) {
              return Promise.resolve(mozResult).then(function(complete) {
                return complete
              })
            }
          }

        })

    };

    function handleEntries(entry) {
      let file = "webkitGetAsEntry" in entry ? entry.webkitGetAsEntry() : entry
      return Promise.resolve(file);
    }

    function handleFile(entry) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (entry.isFile) {
          entry.file(function(file) {
            listFile(file, entry.fullPath).then(resolve)
          })
        } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
          var reader = entry.createReader();
          reader.readEntries(webkitReadDirectories.bind(null, entry, handleFile, resolve))
        } else {
          var entries = [entry];
          return entries.reduce(function(promise, file) {
              return promise.then(function() {
                return listDirectory(file)
              })
            }, Promise.resolve())
            .then(function() {
              return Promise.all(entries.map(function(file) {
                return listFile(file)
              })).then(resolve)
            })
        }
      })

      function webkitReadDirectories(entry, callback, resolve, entries) {
        console.log(entries);
        return listDirectory(entry).then(function(currentDirectory) {
          console.log(`iterating ${currentDirectory.name} directory`, entry);
          return entries.reduce(function(promise, directory) {
            return promise.then(function() {
              return callback(directory)
            });
          }, Promise.resolve())
        }).then(resolve);
      }

    }

    function listDirectory(entry) {
      console.log(entry);
      return Promise.resolve(entry);
    }

    function listFile(file, path) {
      path = path || file.webkitRelativePath || "/" + file.name;
      console.log(`reading ${file.name}, size: ${file.size}, path:${path}`);
      webkitResult.push(file);
      return Promise.resolve(webkitResult)
    };

    function processFiles(files) {
      Promise.all([].map.call(files, function(file, index) {
          return handleEntries(file, index).then(handleFile)
        }))
        .then(function() {
          console.log("complete", webkitResult);
          res = webkitResult;
          res.reduce(function(promise, track) {
            return promise.then(function() {
              return playMusic(track)
            })
          }, displayFiles(res))
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          alert(err.message);
        })
    }

    if ("getFilesAndDirectories" in event.target) {
      return (event.type === "drop" ? event.dataTransfer : event.target).getFilesAndDirectories()
        .then(function(dir) {
          if (dir[0] instanceof Directory) {
            console.log(dir)
            return mozReadDirectories(dir, dir[0].path || path)
              .then(function(complete) {
                console.log("complete:", webkitResult);
                event.target.value = null;
              });
          } else {
            if (dir[0] instanceof File && dir[0].size > 0) {
              return Promise.resolve(dir)
                .then(function() {
                  console.log("complete:", mozResult);
                  res = mozResult;
                  res.reduce(function(promise, track) {
                    return promise.then(function() {
                      return playMusic(track)
                    })
                  }, displayFiles(res))
                })
            } else {
              if (dir[0].size == 0) {
                throw new Error("could not process '" + dir[0].name + "' directory" + " at drop event at firefox, upload folders at 'Choose folder...' input");
              }
            }
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          alert(err)
        })
    }

    files = event.target.files;

    if (files) {
      processFiles(files)
    }

  }

  function displayFiles(files) {
    select.innerHTML = "";
    return Promise.all(files.map(function(file, index) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (/^audio/.test(file.type)) { /* do stuff, that is all code currently within Promise resolver function */ } else { /* proceed to next file */
          resolve()
        }
        var option = new Option(file.name, index);
        select.appendChild(option);
        resolve()
      })
    }))
  }

  function handleSelectedSong(event) {
    if (res.length) {
      var index = select.value;
      var track = res[index];
      playMusic(track)
        .then(function(filename) {
          console.log(filename + " playback completed")
        })
    } else {
      console.log("No songs to play")
    }
  }

  function playMusic(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      audio.pause();
      audio.onended = function() {
        audio.onended = null;
        if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        resolve(file.name);
      }
      if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      audio.load();
      audio.src = url;
      audio.play();
      audioLabel.textContent = file.name;
      context = context || new AudioContext();
      src = src || context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      src.disconnect(context);

      var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      src.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(context.destination);

      analyser.fftSize = 16384;

      var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
      console.log(bufferLength);

      var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
      var WIDTH = canvas.width;
      var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

      var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 32;
      var barHeight;
      var x = 0;

      function renderFrame() {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
        x = 0;

        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#1b1b1b";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
          barHeight = dataArray[i];


          ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(5,155,45)"
          ctx.fillRect(x, (((HEIGHT - barHeight - 5 % barHeight) + (20 % HEIGHT - barHeight))), barWidth, barHeight + 20 % HEIGHT);

          x += barWidth + 2;
        }
      }

      renderFrame();
    })

  }

  input.addEventListener("change", processDirectoryUpload);
  select.addEventListener("change", handleSelectedSong);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="window.innerWidth" height="window.innerHeight"></canvas>
<div id="content">
  <label class="custom-file-upload">
  Select Music directory <input id="file" type="file" accept="audio/*" directory allowdirs webkitdirectory/>
   <p style="color: rgb(5,195,5);">Now playing:<label for="audio"></label></p>

  <p style="color: rgb(5,195,5);">Select Song</p>
  <select id="select">
    </select>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
```

Comment: I'm not experienced in analyzing JavaScript performance for telling why it happens but I did some profiling(DevTools' Performance tab) and it looks like after a song change each time the browser spends more and more time scripting than idling: https://pastebin.com/RV97UraD Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like noted by yuriy636, you are starting a new animation for every new song, without never stopping the previous one.
So when you played 5 songs, you still have 5 visualizations rendering loop running at every frame, and 5 analyzers.

The best to do here is to refactor your code :

- create a single analyzer, only update which stream feeds it
- make the canvas animation autonomous, declare it once at first load
- since you've got only one `<canvas>`, start only one rendering animation

When using a single analyzer, your render doesn't use anything new when you change the source, it's always the same canvas, the same analyzer, the same visualization.

Here is a quick proof of concept, really dirty, but I hope you'll be able to undertstand what I did and why.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("file");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  var selectLabel = document.querySelector("label[for=select]");
  var audioLabel = document.querySelector("label[for=audio]");
  var select = document.querySelector("select");


  var viz = null;

  // removed all the IDK what it was meant for directory special handlers

  function displayFiles() {
    select.innerHTML = "";
    // that's all synchronous, why Promises ?
    res = Array.prototype.slice.call(input.files);
    res.forEach(function(file, index) {
      if (/^audio/.test(file.type)) {
        var option = new Option(file.name, index);
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
    });

    if (res.length) {
      var analyser = initAudioAnalyser();
      viz = initVisualization(analyser);
      // pre-select the first song ?
      handleSelectedSong();
      audio.pause();
    }
  }

  function handleSelectedSong(event) {
    if (res.length) {
      var index = select.value;
      var track = res[index];
      playMusic(track)
        .then(function(filename) {
          console.log(filename + " playback completed")
        })
      viz.play();
    } else {
      console.log("No songs to play")
    }
  }

  function playMusic(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var url = audio.src;
      audio.pause();
      audio.onended = function() {
        audio.onended = null;
        // arguablily useless here since blobURIs are just pointers to real file on the user's system
        if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        resolve(file.name);
      }

      if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      //      audio.load(); // would just set a 404 since you revoked the URL just before
      audio.src = url;
      audio.play();
      audioLabel.textContent = file.name;

    });
  }

  function initAudioAnalyser() {
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 16384;

    var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    src.connect(analyser);
    src.connect(context.destination);

    return analyser;

  }

  function initVisualization(analyser) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;

    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 32;
    var barHeight;
    var x = 0;

    var paused = true;
    
    function renderFrame() {
      if (!paused) {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
      } else {
        return;
      }
      x = 0;

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#1b1b1b";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(5,155,45)"
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];
        // micro-optimisation, but concatenating all the rects in a single shape is easier for the CPU
        ctx.rect(x, (((HEIGHT - barHeight - 5 % barHeight) + (20 % HEIGHT - barHeight))), barWidth, barHeight + 20 % HEIGHT);
        x += barWidth + 2;
      }
      ctx.fill();
    }
    var viz = window.viz = {
      play: function() {
        if(paused){
          paused = false;
          renderFrame();
          }
      },
      pause: function() {
        paused = true;
        clearTimeout(pauseTimeout);
        pauseTimeout = null;
      },
    };
    // we can even add auto pause linked to the audio element
    var pauseTimeout = null;
    audio.onpause = function() {
      // let's really do it in 2s to keep the tear down effect
      pauseTimeout = setTimeout(viz.pause, 2000);
    }
    audio.onplaying = function() {
      clearTimeout(pauseTimeout);
      // we were not playing
      if(!pauseTimeout){
        viz.play();
        }
    }
    return viz;
  }

  input.addEventListener("change", displayFiles);
  select.addEventListener("change", handleSelectedSong);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="window.innerWidth" height="window.innerHeight"></canvas>
<div id="content">
  <label class="custom-file-upload">
  Select Music directory <input id="file" type="file" accept="audio/*" directory allowdirs webkitdirectory/>
   <p style="color: rgb(5,195,5);">Now playing:<label for="audio"></label></p>

  <p style="color: rgb(5,195,5);">Select Song</p>
  <select id="select">
    </select>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
```

Comment: I misinterpreted what you said "When using a single analyzer, your render doesn't use anything new when you change the source, it's always the same canvas, the same analyzer, the same visualization. " I thought you meant that no matter which song was selected It would always have the same visual appearance on the canvas. and got confused. Anywho this definitely works.

Comment: I did notice a slight problem however. If you press play/pause quickly before the 2 second time runs out It starts to do the same thing as before slowing down each time. you can sorta fix it by pausing again and waiting 2 seconds.

Comment: @NickHewitt you're right, dunno what I've done. Reintroduced the original problem for no good reasons... Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. can I request on last thing? before implementing this  code I was playing around with changing the bar's fill style like so `var r = 75 * (i/bufferLength),
        g = barHeight + ((i/bufferLength) +85),
        b = 50;
  
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";` How would I got about doing this now as the fill style is set before the array is made? I tried removing the line above the arrary and placing that in for loop and as I thought it would it caused problems.

Comment: Ah in this case, remove this modification and set back your fillRect

Comment: thanks for all your help. if you want to see some working examples with styling and stuff  visit [gmtrash.cf](http://gmtrash.cf)